# Is InitializingBean and DisposableBean marker Interface?

Tags: java, spring, interface

Marker interface means interface which have **no** methods. Then why we call the  **InitializingBean** and **DisposableBean** interface as a marker interface, even though it has **afterPropertiesSet()** and **destroy()** method respectively.

Comment: Who calls it marker interface?

Comment: Add a link reference on the documentation you refer to. In recent versions, I don't see this terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, and spring open an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPR-4499) that was fixed by renaming from marker to callback interface

> I've used the term "callback interfaces" there now.

Original text taken from excerpt from the 3rd Chapter of the official Spring Framework documentation:
3.5.1. Lifecycle callbacks

> The Spring Framework provides several marker interfaces to change the behavior of your bean in the container; they include InitializingBean and DisposableBean.